# Functional coverage problem using with instead of iff

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module tb;
  logic [1:0] a,b;
  logic sel;
  
  covergroup c;
    option.per_instance = 1;
    coverpoint a{
      wildcard bins a_={2'b??} with (sel);
    }
    coverpoint b{
      wildcard bins b_={2'b??} iff (!sel);
    }
  endgroup
    
    c ci;
    
    initial begin
      ci=new();
      repeat(10) begin
        a=$random;
        b=$random;
        sel=$random;
        $display("%d %d %d",a,b,sel);
        ci.sample();
        #1;
      end
    end
    
endmodule
```

Coverage is not showing when I am using `with`, but when I use `iff` in place of `with`, it's working.  What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with` clause in a bin expression gets evaluated once at the point when the `covergroup` gets constructed and determines the set of which bin values that get created as part of a `coverpoint`. Since `sel` is uninitialized at that point, there are no bins created for `coverpoint a`.

The `iff` clause in a bin expression gets evaluated each time the `covergroup` gets sampled and is effectively a *sample enable* expression. It has no effect on the selection of bin values created.

Most likely using `iff` matches your intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code on VCS, I get a helpful compile error:

```
Error-[FCIWCS] Invalid 'with' clause specification
tb.sv, 8
tb, "a_cp"
  The 'with' clause specified on the coverpoint bin does not have any impact 
  and is invalid; it should contain at least one occurence of the 'item' 
  keyword.
  Please remove or correct the clause and compile
```

Replacing `sel` with `item` works:

```
coverpoint a{
  wildcard bins a_={2'b??} with (item);
}
```

However, running the code on Cadence's simulator still produces a compile error:

> with expression is not supported for wildcard bin.

Using `iff` is more portable.

Comment: The error message form VCS is incorrect. There is nothing in the LRM that says that there must be at least on occurrence of the LRM. See https://verificationacademy.com/forums/coverage/clause-error#reply-108483.